# Custom NSWindowController subclass

Tags: cocoa, swift

I've been playing around with Swift in a little Mac application.

I've been trying to add a non-optional instance variable, but it seems as if I have to override two init methods. The code I've ended up with (that compiles) looks like this:

```
class CustomWindowController: NSWindowController {
  var items: [Int]

  required init(coder: NSCoder!) {
    items = [1, 2, 3]
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  override init(window: NSWindow!) {
    items = [1, 2, 3]
    super.init(window: window)
  }
}
```

I tried to abstract out the `items` initialisation, but it won't compile because "`self is used before super init call". This is what I tried:

```
class CustomWindowController: NSWindowController {
  var items: [Int]

  required init(coder: NSCoder!) {
    setup()
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  override init(window: NSWindow!) {
    setup()
    super.init(window: window)
  }

  func setup() {
    items = [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

I'm a little confused. These are my questions:

1. Why are there be two designated initialisers that I have to override? I thought there was generally one?
2. What's the difference between `override` and `required` and why do I need different ones on each of the initialisers?
3. Is there a way to abstract the initialisation code?

Answer (score 1):

The blog post provided more details: http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/08/initializing-view-controllers-in-swift.html